# Skew Line in progress bar android

Tags: android, canvas, android-progressbar

I want to realize effect of progress bar with skew line.

[image]

Can i custom progress bar in this way?
Or i have to draw on canvas?

I started to do it on the canvas, but then I realized what I was doing something wrong

```
 @Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    int width = getMeasuredWidth();
    int height = getMeasuredHeight();
    mPaint.setColor(backgroundColor);

    backgroundRect = new RectF(0, 0, width, height);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(backgroundRect, 15, 15, mPaint);

    mPaint.reset();
    mPaint.setColor(progressColor);
    checkProgress();
    int xProgress = width * progress / max;
    progressRect = new RectF(0, 0, xProgress, height);


    canvas.drawRoundRect(progressRect, 15, 15, mPaint);


    //triangle
    mPaint.reset();
    mPaint.setColor(backgroundColor);
    Path path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(xProgress, 0);
    path.lineTo(0, height);
    path.lineTo(xProgress - 50, 0);
    path.lineTo(0, height);
    path.lineTo(xProgress, 0);
    path.close();
    canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);
}
```

Advise please something